# Utilizar Redis na prática

Tags: modelagem, redis

Estou com dificuldades em perceber na prática onde usar o Redis em um ecommerce, por exemplo.

Estou lendo um livro mas não consigo perceber o que tenho que levar em conta na hora de decidir usar Redis ou não.

O Redis deve ser usado para dados estáticos?

No caso do ecommerce, utilizar Redis para gravar dados do login ou carrinho de compra e depois gravar definitivamente em um banco como MongoDB ou MySql, etc...?

Answer (score 10):

Amigo, eu utilizo Redis em um ecommerce e acho que posso te dar uma ideia bem simples e prática da sua utilização. Antes de usar o Redis eu utilizava memcached então vamos tentar entender em que ponto isso me ajudou.

1º Minha loja tinha muito acesso e eu não poderia toda vez que o usuario fosse no catalogo ou na página de detalhe carregar o produto pelo banco de dados então eu criei uma implementação de "cache" bem simples e comum que é:

1º O usuario pede a pagina de produto de id 14325
2º Meu adapter de dados da minha aplicação ve se existe um chave no redis chamada product_id_14325 (o nome eu estou definindo), caso exista eu retorno o conteudo do redis, ou seja, não consulto no banco.
3º Caso a chave não exista no redis então eu busco no meu banco de dados e o retorno eu passo para o usuario, serializo ele e persisto no redis. Pronto todo o usuario que acessar essa pagina de detalhe ela fica cacheada.

Existem outras abordagens como por exemplo criar um processo para gravar todos seus produtos no cache e deixar com expiration de 1 dia, e pequenas atualizações para produtos modificados, mas isso depente da sua estratégia de cache, o que importa é que o redis tem uma seria de utilidades.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, não percebo porque alguém deu -1, entendo pouco de Redis ainda mas a dica é válida sim, as informações do produto não se altera constantemente.

Comment: Sabe de algum cenário onde se usa o Redis para manter estados de autenticação? Ou seja, o usuário loga e algo é persistido e lido no Redis nas próximas operações? Tenho um cenário que quero fazer autenticação com JWT e usar o Redis mas não sei se se aplica ao caso.

Answer (score 7):

**Bancos NoSQL**, entende-se “Not only SQL”:

> Esses surgiram da necessidade de escalar bancos de dados relacionais com propriedades ACID em projetos web de alta disponibilidade que operam em larga escala. Suas principais características são alta performance, escalabilidade, fácil replicação e suporte a dados estruturados.

Este rompimento com os padrões SQL causa sempre grande repercussão e muitas discussões carregadas de sentimentos e emoções, mas a verdade é que os bancos de dados relacionais ainda servem para resolver muitos problemas que nem sempre (***veja bem, nem sempre***) poderão ser resolvidos com bancos NoSQL, como por exemplo:

> > - Necessidade de forte consistência de dados, tipagem bem definida, etc;
> > - Pesquisas complexas que exigem um modelo relacional dos dados para realizações de instruções e operações de junção, por exemplo;
> > - Dados que excedam a disponibilidade de memória do servidor, por mais que possamos utilizar swap, ninguém quer prejudicar a performance neste caso.

**NoSQL Redis:**

***Armazenamento de sessões de usuários***

> Este é um modelo muito simples de como utilizar o Redis para salvar as informações da sessão de um usuário.
>
> Para cada sessão, **gera-se uma chave que é gravada no cookie do navegador**. Com essa chave, o sistema tem acesso a um ***hash*** com informações desta sessão: status do login, produtos e publicidades clicadas, preferências de idioma e outras configurações temporais, que perdem a validade após algumas horas.

O benefício de não guardar tais informações de sessão diretamente no cookie é evidente: ganhamos a ***segurança de integridade dos dados***, não correndo o risco de algum usuário malicioso modificá-los. Com o Redis, utilizamos operações simples de get/set para acessar estes dados diretamente da memória do servidor (ou servidores, caso exista mais de um), ***sem desperdício de recursos***, graças ao eficiente ***sistema de expiração*** promovida por este NoSQL.

O algoritmo de expiração não monitora 100% das chaves que podem expirar. Assim como a maioria dos sistemas de cache as chaves são expiradas quando algum cliente tenta acessá-la. Se a chave estiver expirada o valor não é retornado e o registro é removido do banco.

Em bancos que gravam muitos dados que perdem a validade com o tempo, como neste exemplo, algumas chaves nunca seriam acessadas novamente consequentemente elas nunca seriam removidas. Essas chaves precisam ser removidas de alguma maneira, então a cada segundo o Redis testa um conjunto randômico de chaves que possam estar expiradas.  O algoritmo é simples, a cada execução:

> > - Testa 100 chaves com expiração setada.
> > - Deleta todas as chaves expiradas.
> > - Se mais de 25 chaves forem inválidas o algoritmo recomeça do 1.

Esse lógica probabilística continua a expirar até que o nosso conjunto de keys válidas seja próximo de 75% dos registros.

Fonte de pesquisa: [Link NoSQL Redis](http://blog.boo-box.com/br/institucional/usando-banco-de-dados-nosql-redis/)

Comment: Agradeço o seu tempo mas já tinha lido isso, o que eu queria era na prática saber como aplicar em um ecommerce, esse texto acima é como estudar teoria para montar uma bicicleta, na prática você vai cair!

Answer (score 1):

Eu administro uma plataforma de desenvolvimento de sites e nela usamos Redis e MySQL.

O MySQL, obviamente, armazena todos os dados do sistema, inclusive os dados que renderizam os sites. Mas por quê então eu tenho um banco redis junto com esse MySQL? Simples: velocidade.

Por fornecer sites, eu sempre quero que o site abra da forma mais rápida possível, tanto para melhorar o SEO quanto para melhorar a experiência dos usuários, e pra alcançar essa marca, eu utilizo um banco redis pra armazenar os dados que renderizam os sites(que no caso são todos em JSON), já que por ser um banco que roda em memória, o acesso é muito mais rápido do que se o sistema tivesse que, de alguma forma, consultar o sistema de arquivos em busca desses dados. Esse banco redis é atualizado sempre que o cliente faz alguma atualização em algum conteúdo que seja relevante para a renderização do site ou caso a nossa VPS seja reiniciada.

Resumindo, o Redis é extremamente útil, como foi meu caso, para armazenar dados que precisem ser entregues de forma rápida.

Agora imagine essa mesma situação, para um e-commerce.

O cliente vai e cadastra as mercadorias, e esses dados são enviados pra um banco em memória pra ser consumido pelo seu client. Isso, entre muitas coisas, melhoria a experiência dos visitantes do site pois reduziria bastante o tempo de carregamento dos dados de produto, já que ao invés de ter que consultar o sistema de arquivos ou uma api, os dados já estariam disponíveis na memória do servidor. Isso deve ser muito levado em consideração, já que sistemas mais lentos tem chances maiores de perder acessos por conta de carregamentos demorados, que podem causar erros de timeout, por exemplo.